# Go back a page with clicked link and refresh at the same time? Stuck with cross browser support

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having cross browser issues with this code to go back a page "**and refresh at the same time**".  I need it to work to correctly update my shopping cart in my eCommerce store.  I can only get it to work with Safari.  Please can someone kindly tell me how to fix it for cross browser support...

```
<?php
    echo "<p style=\"padding: 0px; margin: 0\"><a style=\"padding: 0px; margin: 0\" href='javascript:window.location = document.referrer;'>Go back</a></p>";
?>
```

Thanks! :)

As I understand, it's an issue with HTTP Referrer not being passed/supported on some browsers with window.location?  Just don't know how to fix it.

Edit;

Just tested this and it doesn't refresh the page after, so my cart items are lost.  Still on the hunt for a fix please ;)

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
 }
 </script>
```

Edit; The top echo statement seems to be working by my tests today, not sure what happened there?  If anyone has any go back and refresh page at same time code, please do post and i'll leave this open and confirm any other working cross browser.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `window.history.back()`. This will also reload your page :)

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be a refresh? You might be conflating two issues.

However, if it really does have to be a refresh you could try

```
function goBack() {
    var ref = document.referrer;
    window.location.href = ref;
}
```

That should load the page similar to clicking a link.

Comment: It has to be refresh to update my shopping cart as for some reason the item aren't sticking when you simply go back a page, which I guess would be typical. Think of it like a continue shopping button but going back to the same page you were on previously.  Unfortunately I can't think how to do this as my categories for products are are echo'd from a database via PHP, so a simple navigate to url would send users back to the same page and not that which they were on previously.  window.location does not work for all browsers so i'm led to believe in tests... Hope you can help!